# Use a div as a submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html

I want to transform a div composed of image + text (for translation) in a submit button. Is it possible?

I managed to use the image as submit but the text is not a link and it gives a 'broken' feeling to the whole image + text

Comment: Only with javascript... are you looking for a non javascript method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Jquery usage.

```
$('div').click(function () {
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 15):

```
<div onclick="document.myform.submit()"></div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do it in two ways.

1. You can use a button with type submit and use CSS to style it as a `div`
2. Add an onClick on the div, and submit the form on the click event.

For method 2 you can either do it through jQuery or without, With plain js

```
<script>
    function submitOnClick(formName){
        document.forms[formName].submit();
    }
</script>
<form id="myForm" ...>
    ....
    <div onclick="submitOnClick('myForm')>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Trevor's answer shows how to do it with jQuery.
In his example just replace the `'div'` and `'form'` with the ids of your div and form as this:

If ids of div and form are `myDiv` and `myForm` specify them as `'#myDiv'` and `'#myForm'`, here `#` is used to specify the following string is an id of an element.