# submiting form on div click with js

Tags: forms, jquery, coffeescript

I have a div element and I want that when I click on it i submit a form which is hidden.

**div code**

```
<div class="a15 training-exercise">
    some text
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/trainings/1/training_exercises/5" data-remote="true" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put"></div>  
        <input id="training_exercise_done" name="training_exercise[done]" type="text" value="false">
        <input name="commit" type="submit" value="subit">
    </form>
</div>
```

**coffescript**

```
$ ->
    $('.training-exercise').click ->
        if $(this).hasClass('done')
            $(this).removeClass('done')
            $(this).find('input:text').val(false)
            $(this).closest("form").submit()
        else
            $(this).addClass('done')
            $(this).find('input:text').val(true)
            $(this).closest('form').submit()
```

**corresponding JS code**

```
$(function() {
  return $('.training-exercise').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('done')) {
      $(this).removeClass('done');
      $(this).find('input:text').val(false);
      return $(this).closest("form").submit;
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('done');
      $(this).find('input:text').val(true);
      return $(this).closest('form').submit;
    }
  });
});
```

i didn't put checkbox for true and false because `f.checkbox` gave me some strange results

The problem here is:

1) Everything is happening except form submitting

2) form has `visibility: hidden;` and it is hidden, but there is empty space where the form is, I want that it looks like there is nothing there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463246/use-a-div-as-a-submit-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that form selecting didn't work (although it work when I tried from console)

The solution that works is:

```
$(this).find('input:submit').submit()
```

Answer (score 2):

For **1st** problem, try

```
$(function() {
  $('.training-exercise').click(function() {
      var element = $(this);
         if (element.hasClass('done')) {
         element.removeClass('done');
         element.find('input:text').val(false);
         element.closest('form').submit(); //<-- brackets here.
      } else {
         element.addClass('done');
         element.find('input:text').val(true);
         element.closest('form').submit();
      }
   });
});
```

For **2nd** problem use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden.`

Comment: Just to tidy this a little, you don't need the `return` on the click handler, and you should really cache `$(this)` in to a variable. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, makes the answer better.

Comment: sorry i converted my coffescript to this code because people usually ask that, I updated with coffee script +1 for second problem

Comment: catching $(this) was not the problem, using `submit()` was.